# MySQL select from dynamic database and table query

Tags: mysql, database, stored-procedures

Stored Proc Definition:

```
DECLARE dbName varchar(255);
DECLARE tableName varchar(255);
DECLARE fullPath varchar(255);
DECLARE conditions varchar(255);

SET dbName = idbname;
SET tableName = itablename;
SET fullPath = CONCAT("'",dbName,"'",'.',"'",tableName,"'");
SET checkExists = 0;
```

I am creating a stored proc where the dbname and tablename are dynamic, however I am stuck on the select aspect of this query.

I am trying to repalce the _test.`user` with values passed into the stored proc.

```
SELECT count(*) INTO checkExists FROM `_test`.`user` WHERE id = 1;
```

However this line throws an error

```
SELECT count(*) INTO checkExists FROM fullPath WHERE id = 1;
```

**Error:**

```
Procedure execution failed
1146 - Table 'dbname.fullpath' doesn't exist
```

I have also tried CONCAT() like this

```
set conditions = CONCAT('SELECT count(*) INTO ',checkExists, ' FROM ', fullPath, ' WHERE id=', 1);
```

However I can't figure out even how to use this in a select? Help is appreciated.

Comment: See if this helps : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html

Comment: Yes prepared statements would work with my concat statement. I am trying to find out why I cannot do that select normally by passing in a variable. Or if its possible

Answer (score 0):

I like to do these modifications using `replace()`.  Something like this:

```
replace(replace('SELECT count(*) INTO checkExists FROM `<dbname>`.`<tname>` WHERE id = 1',
                '<tname>', v_tablename
               ), '<dbname>', v_databasename
       )
```

You may also want to use `v_fullpath` somewhere.  I'm not really sure what query you actually want to create.

I'm not sure why you have a variable called `checkExists`, when it seems to be the destination file.  However, I would suggest that you prepend all your local variables with something to distinguish them from column names.

Comment: I am comparing rows in two tables, if a row exists in table 2 that is not in table 1 I would perform a delete that exist on two separate dbs. Also, I don't understand how to use the replace in this instance?

Comment: @Harry . . . You should ask another question with a valid description of what you are doing.  This question is clearly about one table and a bunch of variables.  Modifying a question after it has answers is impolite, because it can invalidate the answer.